# How to add multiple network blocks in command Line?

Tags: networking, wifi, network-interface, wpa-supplicant

I want to add network blocks into `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_suppplicant.conf` file.

The original file looks like,

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="HOMEWIFI"
    psk="12345678"
}
```

and I would like to add new network blocks in command line, finally the file would be :

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="HOMEWIFI"
    psk="12345678"
}

network={
    ssid="NEW_WIFI"
    psk="00000000"
}
```

I want to do this not with a manual process, but via the **command line**.

I read https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant this, 
so If I run this

```
# wpa_supplicant -B -i interface -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
# wpa_cli 
> scan
OK
> scan_results
> add_network
0
> set_network 0 ssid "NEW_WIFI"
> set_network 0 psk "0000000"
> enable_network 0
CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection completed.
> save_config
OK
```

will add a new network block successfully.

But I believe there is a simpler way. That way abovetakes time, and looks verbose. Is there a more elegant and simple way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to run `wpa_cli` , just configure your `wpa_suppplicant.conf` through `wpa_passphrase` then connect :

```
wpa_passphrase <SSID> <Passphrase> >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Or:

```
sudo sh -c 'wpa_passphrase <SSID> <Passphrase> >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf'
```

then:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -i <interface> -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
dhclient <interface>
```

Alternative methode :

You can use `nmtui` the Network Manager Text User Interface ; run `nmtui` then configure your network .

Also you can use `wicd-curses` , install it then run `wicd-curses` from the terminal , it's the easy way to configure/connect to your network from the terminal

Comment: Can I one more or should I start new thread? Your command only works as root user. even I type `sudo wpa_passphrase ... ` permission denied. I have to log in as root user through type `sudo -i`. Is there a way to run that command in root user like add prefix `sudo` without login?

Comment: @Juntae i update my answer